# MDS: Are there measures of stress that are not affected by the number of objects?

Tags: multidimensional-scaling

This question flows naturally out of [a previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214365/mds-is-kruskals-stress-1-affected-by-scale-of-the-data-or-the-number-of-point), in which it was explained that Stress-1 is somewhat impacted by the number of objects.

You can assume that the number of objects in the smaller set will always be at least 20, and probably much more. By "measures of stress that are not affected by the number of objects" I mean a measure of stress that is not colossally flawed in some other way, even if it is inferior to Stress-1 in some respects.

Are there any commonly used stress measures that are not affected by the number of objects? If it's not possible to have a sensible stress measure that is not affected by the number of points, why not?

I would also welcome feedback on whether insensitivity to the number of objects is a sensible goal for a stress measure.

Comment: I think that this Q does not deserve yet to be asked as a new one. It adds little to your previous one. You could update (just add "update" paragraphs) that older one with your details / more requests.

Comment: Although I have no aversion to updating questions, I don't see the questions as being particularly similar. The other is about a particular stress measure, while this one is about any stress measure. I admit it is possible that the best answer to each question might cover similar content. However, that's not certain and I won't know until this question has run its course.